# Почему Ajax возвращает error: Bad action

Tags: jquery, ajax, modx

```
    var form = $('.form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/calc',
        method: 'POST',
        data: form,
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

Движок сайта MODx

Возвращается ошибка `{"error":"Bad action"}`

В чем может быть проблема?

**UPD:**
По адресу "/calc" находится ресурс с сниппетом, который содержит php код. В php происходит простое вычисление значений полей формы, которые передаются через Ajax. Результат вычисления возвращается в Ajax в виде простого числа.

Если вместо "/calc" указать любую другу страницу или файл, то ошибка такая же.

Comment: В том, что движок не распознаёт `action`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Из текста ошибки это я понял) А как выявить в где кроется проблема?

Comment: Очевидно что в документации движка. Посмотрите, какие параметры он принимает и добавьте их в запрос.

Comment: Так то совсем ничего не понятно без кода. Сниппет же вы скорее всего используете кэшированным? А попробуйте просто плагин написать и вызывать напрямую просто php файл, какой ответ будет?

Comment: Посмотрите вот эту ветку, у меня была подобная ошибка, может поможет https://modx.pro/help/9081